Always changing value for 1st rendered component
Below are two component for app created in Next.js 14 and Shadcn UI.
Below are two component.
"use client"

import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef, RefCallback } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { ChevronUp, ChevronDown, Menu } from 'lucide-react';
import Quiz from '@/components/quiz/Quiz';
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Card } from "@/components/ui/card";
import { useToast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast";
import { useUserStore } from '@/store/user-store';
import { Loader2 } from 'lucide-react';
import { fetchQuiz } from "@/lib/api";

interface Question {
    questionId: string;
    heading: string;
    description: string;
    options: Array<{
        optionId: string;
        description: string;
    }>;
}

interface RightOption {
    questionId: string;
    rightOption: string[];
    explanation: string;
}

const QuizAttempt: React.FC = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    const quizId = params.quizId as string;
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState<Question[]>([]);
    const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState<Record<string, string[]>>({});
    const [rightOptions, setRightOptions] = useState<RightOption[]>([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
    const [buttonLoading, setButtonLoading] = useState(false);
    const [timeRemaining, setTimeRemaining] = useState(20 * 60);
    const questionRefs = useRef<Record<string, HTMLDivElement | null>>({});
    const setQuestionRef: RefCallback<HTMLDivElement> = (element: HTMLDivElement | null) => {
        if (element) {
            questionRefs.current[element.id] = element;
        }
    };
    const { user } = useUserStore();
    const [quizSummary, setQuizSummary] = useState({ right: 0, wrong: 0, unattempted: 0 });
    const scrollContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [showUpIcon, setShowUpIcon] = useState(false);
    const [showDownIcon, setShowDownIcon] = useState(false);
    const [showTrackingBar, setShowTrackingBar] = useState(false);
    const { toast } = useToast();

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchQuestions = async () => {
            if (!quizId || !user) return;

            try {
                const data = await fetchQuiz(quizId);
                setQuestions(data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching questions:", error);
                toast({
                    title: "Error",
                    description: "Failed to fetch quiz questions",
                    variant: "destructive",
                });
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        fetchQuestions();
    }, [quizId, user, toast]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            setTimeRemaining((prevTime) => {
                if (prevTime <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    submitQuiz();
                    return 0;
                }
                return prevTime - 1;
            });
        }, 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkScroll = () => {
            if (scrollContainerRef.current) {
                const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = scrollContainerRef.current;
                setShowUpIcon(scrollTop > 0);
                setShowDownIcon(scrollTop + clientHeight < scrollHeight);
            }
        };

        const container = scrollContainerRef.current;
        if (container) {
            container.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);
            checkScroll();

            return () => container.removeEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);
        }
    }, [questions]);

    const handleOptionChange = (questionId: string, selectedOption: string[]) => {
        console.log('Updating options for question:', questionId, 'New options:', selectedOption);
        setSelectedOptions((prevSelectedOptions) => ({
            ...prevSelectedOptions,
            [questionId]: selectedOption,
        }));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Updated Selected Options:', selectedOptions);
    }, [selectedOptions]);

    const submitQuiz = async () => {
        if (!quizId || !user) return;

        setButtonLoading(true);
        const payload = Object.entries(selectedOptions).map(([questionId, optionIds]) => ({
            questionId,
            optionIds
        }));

        try {
            const token = await user.getIdToken();
            const response = await fetch(`/api/quiz/submit/${quizId}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(payload)
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to submit quiz');
            }

            const data = await response.json();
            setSubmitted(true);
            setRightOptions(data.quizResponses);

            // Calculate quiz summary
            let right = 0;
            let wrong = 0;
            let unattempted = 0;

            questions.forEach(question => {
                const selectedOptionIds = selectedOptions[question.questionId] || [];
                const correctOptionIds = data.quizResponses.find((q: RightOption) => q.questionId === question.questionId)?.rightOption || [];

                if (selectedOptionIds.length === 0) {
                    unattempted++;
                } else if (arraysEqual(selectedOptionIds.sort(), correctOptionIds.sort())) {
                    right++;
                } else {
                    wrong++;
                }
            });

            setQuizSummary({ right, wrong, unattempted });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            toast({
                title: "Error",
                description: "Failed to submit quiz",
                variant: "destructive",
            });
        } finally {
            setButtonLoading(false);
        }
    };

    const arraysEqual = (a: string[], b: string[]) => {
        if (a.length !== b.length) return false;
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    };

    const formatTime = (seconds: number): string => {
        const mins = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        const secs = seconds % 60;
        return `${mins}:${secs < 10 ? '0' : ''}${secs}`;
    };

    const scrollToQuestion = (questionId: string) => {
        questionRefs.current[questionId]?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        setShowTrackingBar(false);
    };

    const scroll = (direction: 'up' | 'down') => {
        const container = scrollContainerRef.current;
        if (!container) return;

        const scrollStep = direction === 'up' ? -1 : 1;
        let start: number | undefined;
        let previousTimestamp: number | undefined;

        const step = (timestamp: number) => {
            if (start === undefined) {
                start = timestamp;
            }

            const elapsed = timestamp - start;

            if (previousTimestamp !== timestamp) {
                const currentScrollTop = container.scrollTop;
                container.scrollTop += scrollStep;

                if (container.scrollTop === currentScrollTop) {
                    return;
                }

                const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = container;
                setShowUpIcon(scrollTop > 0);
                setShowDownIcon(scrollTop + clientHeight < scrollHeight);
            }

            if (elapsed < 2000) {
                previousTimestamp = timestamp;
                window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
            }
        };

        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    };

    const toggleTrackingBar = () => {
        setShowTrackingBar(!showTrackingBar);
    };

    if (loading) {
        return (
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
                <Loader2 className="w-8 h-8 animate-spin" />
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className="relative flex h-screen dark:bg-gray-900">
            {/* Floating menu icon for mobile */}
            <div className="fixed z-50 bottom-4 right-4 md:hidden">
                <Button
                    onClick={toggleTrackingBar}
                    variant="outline"
                    size="icon"
                >
                    <Menu className="h-4 w-4" />
                </Button>
            </div>

            {/* Question tracking column with auto-scroll */}
            <Card className={`fixed flex flex-col items-center w-64 h-2/3 left-6 top-1/4 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out ${showTrackingBar ? 'translate-x-0' : '-translate-x-full'} md:translate-x-0 md:w-16`}>
                {showUpIcon && (
                    <Button
                        variant="outline"
                        size="icon"
                        className="mb-2"
                        onMouseEnter={() => scroll('up')}
                        onMouseLeave={() => {}}
                    >
                        <ChevronUp className="h-4 w-4" />
                    </Button>
                )}
                <div
                    ref={scrollContainerRef}
                    className="flex-grow w-full p-2 overflow-y-auto scrollbar-hide"
                >
                    {questions.map((question, index) => (
                        <Button
                            key={question.questionId}
                            variant={selectedOptions[question.questionId]?.length > 0 ? "secondary" : "outline"}
                            className="w-full mb-2"
                            onClick={() => scrollToQuestion(question.questionId)}
                        >
                            {index + 1}
                        </Button>
                    ))}
                </div>
                {showDownIcon && (
                    <Button
                        variant="outline"
                        size="icon"
                        className="mt-2"
                        onMouseEnter={() => scroll('down')}
                        onMouseLeave={() => {}}
                    >
                        <ChevronDown className="h-4 w-4" />
                    </Button>
                )}
            </Card>

            {/* Quiz content */}
            <div className="flex-1 max-w-full p-2 md:p-4 md:ml-24 dark:text-white">
                {questions.map((question) => {
                    return (
                        <div
                            key={question.questionId}
                            id={question.questionId}
                            className='mb-8 md:mb-12'
                            ref={setQuestionRef}
                        >
                            <Quiz
                                heading={question.heading}
                                description={question.description}
                                options={question.options}
                                questionId={question.questionId}
                                selectedOptions={selectedOptions[question.questionId] || []}
                                onOptionChange={handleOptionChange}
                                rightOptions={rightOptions}
                                submitted={submitted}
                            />
                        </div>
                    );
                })}

                <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center pb-4'>
                    {submitted ? (
                        <Card className="p-4">
                            <h2 className="text-xl font-bold mb-2">Quiz Summary</h2>
                            <p>Correct: {quizSummary.right}</p>
                            <p>Incorrect: {quizSummary.wrong}</p>
                            <p>Unattempted: {quizSummary.unattempted}</p>
                        </Card>
                    ) : (
                        <Button
                            onClick={submitQuiz}
                            disabled={buttonLoading}
                        >
                            {buttonLoading ? (
                                <>
                                    <Loader2 className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />
                                    Evaluating...
                                </>
                            ) : (
                                'Submit Quiz'
                            )}
                        </Button>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default QuizAttempt;

Below i have added Quiz component.
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { Check, X, Circle, CircleCheck } from 'lucide-react';
import { Card, CardContent } from "@/components/ui/card";
import { Checkbox } from "@/components/ui/checkbox";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import MarkdownRenderer from "@/components/markdown/MarkdownRenderer";

interface Option {
    optionId: string;
    description: string;
}

interface QuizProps {
    heading: string;
    description: string;
    options: Option[];
    questionId: string;
    selectedOptions: string[];
    onOptionChange: (questionId: string, selectedOption: string[]) => void;
    rightOptions: Array<{
        questionId: string;
        rightOption: string[];
        explanation: string;
    }> | null;
    submitted: boolean;
}

const Quiz: React.FC<QuizProps> = ({
                                       heading,
                                       description,
                                       options,
                                       questionId,
                                       selectedOptions,
                                       onOptionChange,
                                       rightOptions,
                                       submitted
                                   }) => {

    const filteredQuestion = rightOptions?.find(item => item.questionId === questionId);

    const handleOptionChange = useCallback((optionId: string) => {
        console.log("Changing option for question:", questionId, "Option:", optionId);
        const newSelected = selectedOptions.includes(optionId)
            ? selectedOptions.filter(id => id !== optionId)
            : [...selectedOptions, optionId];
        console.log("New selected options:", newSelected);
        onOptionChange(questionId, newSelected);
    }, [questionId, selectedOptions, onOptionChange]);

    return (
        <motion.div
            initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 20 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
        >
            <Card className="overflow-hidden">
                <CardContent className="p-6">
                    <h2 className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">{heading}</h2>
                    <div className="mb-6">
                        <MarkdownRenderer>{description}</MarkdownRenderer>
                    </div>
                    <div className="space-y-2">
                        {options.map((option) => (
                            <Selection
                                key={`${questionId}-${option.optionId}`}
                                optionId={option.optionId}
                                description={option.description}
                                selected={selectedOptions}
                                rightOptions={filteredQuestion?.rightOption || []}
                                submitted={submitted}
                                onChange={() => handleOptionChange(option.optionId)}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    {submitted && filteredQuestion && (
                        <motion.div
                            initial={{ opacity: 0, height: 0 }}
                            animate={{ opacity: 1, height: 'auto' }}
                            transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
                            className="mt-6 p-4 rounded-md bg-secondary"
                        >
                            <p className="font-semibold">Explanation:</p>
                            <p>{filteredQuestion.explanation}</p>
                        </motion.div>
                    )}
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </motion.div>
    );
};

interface SelectionProps {
    optionId: string;
    description: string;
    selected: string[];
    rightOptions: string[];
    submitted: boolean;
    onChange: () => void;
}

const Selection: React.FC<SelectionProps> = ({
                                                 optionId,
                                                 description,
                                                 selected,
                                                 rightOptions,
                                                 submitted,
                                                 onChange
                                             }) => {
    const isSelected = selected.includes(optionId);
    const isRightOption = rightOptions.includes(optionId);
    const isAttempted = selected.length > 0;

    const getOptionColor = () => {
        if (isSelected && isRightOption && submitted) return 'border-green-600 dark:border-green-400 bg-green-50 dark:bg-green-900';
        if (isSelected && !isRightOption && submitted) return 'border-red-600 dark:border-red-400 bg-red-50 dark:bg-red-900';
        if (isSelected) return 'border-primary bg-primary/10';
        if (!isSelected && isRightOption && submitted && !isAttempted) return 'border-blue-600 dark:border-blue-400 bg-blue-50 dark:bg-blue-900';
        if (!isSelected && isRightOption && submitted) return 'border-green-600 dark:border-green-400 bg-green-50 dark:bg-green-900';
        return 'border-input';
    };

    const getIcon = () => {
        if (isSelected && isRightOption && submitted) return <Check className="text-green-600 dark:text-green-400" />;
        if (isSelected && !isRightOption && submitted) return <X className="text-red-600 dark:text-red-400" />;
        if (!isSelected && isRightOption && submitted) return <Check className="text-green-600 dark:text-green-400" />;
        if (isSelected && !submitted) return <CircleCheck className="text-primary" />;
        return <Circle className="text-muted-foreground" />;
    };

    return (
        <div className={cn(
            "flex items-center space-x-2 rounded-md border p-4",
            getOptionColor(),
            submitted ? "cursor-not-allowed" : "cursor-pointer"
        )}>
            <Checkbox
                id={optionId}
                checked={isSelected}
                onCheckedChange={onChange}
                disabled={submitted}
                className="sr-only"
            />
            <Label
                htmlFor={optionId}
                className="flex flex-1 items-center space-x-3 text-sm font-normal"
            >
                <span className="flex-shrink-0">{getIcon()}</span>
                <span>{description}</span>
            </Label>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Quiz;

Issue is when multiple Quiz component is rendered when i change option of 2,3... component  it always change value of 1st component.
 const handleOptionChange = useCallback((optionId: string) => {
        console.log("Changing option for question:", questionId, "Option:", optionId);
        const newSelected = selectedOptions.includes(optionId)
            ? selectedOptions.filter(id => id !== optionId)
            : [...selectedOptions, optionId];
        console.log("New selected options:", newSelected);
        onOptionChange(questionId, newSelected);
    }, [questionId, selectedOptions, onOptionChange]);

Above method is always picking first component questionId.

It would be better if you share the relevant code in codesandbox or somewhere to take a look.
